# How to get values of JSONP returned array

Tags: json, ajax, jsonp

i'm getting data on local from cross domain.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://sunnah.com/ajax/urdu/bukhari/1?callback=items",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'items',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    success: function (data) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data)
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

i can see returned json array like `[{"urduURN":"4000010","collection":"bukhari"}....]` that can be seen given [URL](http://sunnah.com/ajax/urdu/bukhari/1?callback=items). but i am unable to get anything in `console.log(data)` i wish also to put it's values to html element which is returning from `data` doing loop. please apprise me  where i'm doing mistake?

Comment: The server is not returning JSONP. It simply returns JSON.

Comment: Also, in case it is a simple JSON request, you don't need to `$.parseJSON` jQuery AJAX response - it is a JSON object already. You can simply access it like `data.something`.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev thank you for your info but i have tried already without `$.perseJSON` and `success`. still i was unable to show anything in `console.log()` but i can see data in `NETWORK` tab of chrome under `name` column. atleast it should show something like `console.log(data);` as object? or one of it's value `data.bookNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://sunnah.com/ajax/urdu/bukhari/1?callback=items",
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonpCallback: 'items',
jsonp: 'callback',
success: function (data) {
    var strData = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(strData );
}
});
```

Comment: appreciate your answer but problem still stands. before `console.log()` i tried a `alert()` which also didn't work. then i added `,success: function (data) {... } ,
     error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         alert("some error");
     }` now this time it alerted "some error". it seems its unsuccessful while data is being returned?